# docker installation editions? for hyper v enabled PC

Tags: docker

I have windows 10 home edition. I checked my hyper v capabilites of the machine.all four of it says ÝES. Should I get the docker for windows or the toolbox. I am confused.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You won’t be able to use Docker Desktop for Windows Home edition. Docker Desktop supports professional edition not the home edition. The only option you have is Docker Toolbox.

Answer (score 0):

See [official guide](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/#what-to-know-before-you-install): just follow them, don't try to make any hacker as I think this maybe waste effort to do that. For you, choose docker toolbox please.

> - **README FIRST for Docker Toolbox and Docker Machine users:** Docker Desktop for Windows requires Microsoft Hyper-V to run. The Docker Desktop for Windows installer enables Hyper-V for you, if needed, and restarts your machine. After Hyper-V is enabled, VirtualBox no longer works, but any VirtualBox VM images remain. VirtualBox VMs created with docker-machine (including the default one typically created during Toolbox install) no longer start. These VMs cannot be used side-by-side with Docker Desktop for Windows. However, you can still use docker-machine to manage remote VMs.
> - **System Requirements:**
>
>   - Windows 10 64bit: Pro, Enterprise or Education (Build 15063 or later).
>   - Virtualization is enabled in BIOS. Typically, virtualization is enabled by default. This is different from having Hyper-V enabled. For more detail see Virtualization must be enabled in Troubleshooting.
>   - CPU SLAT-capable feature.
>   - At least 4GB of RAM.
>
> Note: If your system does not meet the requirements to run Docker Desktop for Windows, you can install Docker Toolbox, which uses Oracle Virtual Box instead of Hyper-V.

Answer (score -1):

Enter to your BIOS, and try to enable Virtualization Technology(Vtx) or AMD-V